# Status Bar not hiding - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I recently made a change to my project (Adding SWRevealController and Removing my TabbarController), and all of a sudden my status bar won't hide.

I have tried the following solutions:

1. Hiding via IB Hiding in my base view controller using

   ```
   (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
   ```
2. Hiding using this code in viewdidload.

   ```
   [self prefersStatusBarHidden]; 
   [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
   ```
3. Adding **View controller-based status bar appearance** set to NO to the plist file.

Comment: You want to hide the status bar in whole project or only in some view controllers?

Comment: I wanted it hidden in the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the status bar in your project General Settings.

Click on YourApplication Target. Click on General Tab.

select `Hide During Application Launch` option in Deployment Info Section.

I am adding a screenShot for  your convenience.

[image]

Your Project provide itself the option of hiding the status bar so why to add the same property in the .plist file.

Enjoy Coding...!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your apps plist file add a row call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO.

Comment: If you set this to YES you can hide with

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;`
`[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES; }
```

Comment: I had tried this as well.  see above.  I just didn't complete the full method signature

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% convinced, but the problem seemed to resolve when I added "Status bar is initially hidden" = YES to my PLIST file.   I don't understand why, but it seems to have done the trick.